# Calculated django model field that depends on all the table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class MyModel():
    total_time = IntegerField()
    total_score = IntegerField()
```

and I want to add a property or a field to this model which will be called *rate* and will be calculated according to those fields but on all the table, 
So if we have these models:

```
 1. total time - 1, total score - 3
 2. Total time - 2, total score - 2
 3. Total time - 3, total score - 1
```

My expectation is: if the `rate` is calculated by `time`, number 3 will be rated 1, but if it is calculated by `score` number one will be rated 1.

What is the best practice for such a case?

EDIT: 
To clear I want if now someone is entered like this:
4. total time - 4 total score - 4
He will be rated 1 in both but all the others will be rated according to the new rate

Thank in advance !!

Comment: Please clear your question. I guess you can override the save() method and calculate the field there.

Comment: Cleared the question - I want it to be updated love according to all the records

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate anything and override any field.

```py
class MyModel():
    total_time = IntegerField
    total_score = IntegerField

    def save(self):
        # do calculations here
        # example: total_score = 3
        return super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Comment: I want it to be updated according to all the records in the table, so every time there is a new record all the rates will be changed according to the new record